# Извлечение из списка определенного количества элементов вложенных списков\кортежей

Tags: python, список

Задача на оптимизацию кода:

Есть вот такой список кортежей:

```
['Moscow','NewYork', 2), ('Washington','London', 1), ('London','NewYork', 4)]
```

из него нужно получить вот такой:

```
[('Moscow', 'NewYork'), ('Washington', 'London'), ('London', 'NewYork')]
```

т.е. извлечь только первые 2 элемента каждого картежа.

Есть ли какой то **изящный** способ, кроме использования  генераторов списка и библиотеки Pandas.

Мой код:

```
# исходный список картежей
list_of_tuples_big = [('Moscow','NewYork', 2), ('Washington','London', 1), ('London','NewYork', 4)]
# с помощью генератора оставим только первые два элемента каждого кортежа
list_of_tuples_small = [(city1, city2) for city1, city2, _ in list_of_tuples_big]
```

P.S. Кортеж как элемент списка - это условность, его можно заменить списком.

Comment: Подожди. Кортежы нельзя изменить, меняй на списки, поэтому переписывай их по новоц

Comment: А чем вам не нравится ваш способ с помощью генератора списков? Вполне себе изящный.

Comment: ну тем, что все равно происходит обход списка

Comment: у вас в исходных данных - кортеж. раз у вас итерируемый объект, то в любом случае будет совершаться обход по всему списку/кортежу явно или неявно.

Comment: @strawdog согласен, не учел это. надо было пример сделать с вложенным списком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите через функции, то можно и через функции:

```
list(map(lambda tpl: tpl[:2], list_of_tuples_big))
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой генератор вам кажется более изящным?:

```
lst = [('Moscow','NewYork', 2), ('Washington','London', 1), ('London','NewYork', 4)]
res=[(x[:2]) for x in lst]
```

> [('Moscow', 'NewYork'), ('Washington', 'London'), ('London', 'NewYork')]

Comment: неее) я думал может есть какая нибудь функция)

Comment: @garrythehotdog ну вот если сами напишите, то будет :)

Comment: @garrythehotdog, добавил ответ, где всё функционально :)